# Django editing data and showing info as form field in my model

Tags: python, django, web

I am trying django and stuck here. by the way i am new to django

So when i want to click on Edit button which is in table next to a person's record I want to pass id to access info of that person which I click to my model and show info as values in form fields.I am using form in a model. I am trying to edit a person's info. How can I do it I am using simple  ORM. I am not using a Model form.

Sorry I am not allow to add pics yet.

Comment: Hello there, Welcome to StackOverflow! Please edit your question, so you will get a suitable answer. Read the docs on how to [ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should pass a primary key through dynamic URL. This
[tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HhjnQIpXqPc) will help you.